# Mongoid::Criteria can't modify frozen String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

This perplexes me. A Mongoid::Criteria is not frozen, but if I assign it to a variable in console, it tells me `FrozenError (can't modify frozen String: "#<Mongoid::Criteria`

Why would that be, and how do I fix it?

mongoid (~> 7.3.0)
rails (~> 6.0.0)

[image]

Comment: did you solve the issue?
I started getting this error when upgrading Ruby from 2.7.1 to 2.7.6 (mongoid 7.3.1 and rails 6.0.4.6)

Comment: @UdiCohen nope, I have not solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this issue in IRB repo: https://github.com/ruby/irb/issues/136.
It means the issue was fixed in a later version of IRB, so my suggestion is to force IRB version higher than 2.8 to get the fix.

Just add `gem 'irb', '>= 1.2.8'` to your gemfile and test that it works with your current Ruby version.